# unable to deploy war file in tomcat9 using jenkins

Tags: jenkins, tomcat, tomcat9

I am trying to deploy war file in tomcat but unable to do so. I am using tomcat9. I have configure tomcat9 and its up and active on port 9090 as I am using port 8080 for jenkins. I am running jenkins and tomcat9 in my local Ubuntu 20.04. When I run my jenkins job, I am getting the below logs:

```
Started by user Pritish
Running as SYSTEM
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/deploy-staging
Copied 1 artifact from "package" build number 5
[DeployPublisher][INFO] Attempting to deploy 1 war file(s)
[DeployPublisher][INFO] Deploying /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/deploy-staging/webapp/target/webapp.war to container Tomcat 9.x Remote with context null
ERROR: Build step failed with exception
org.codehaus.cargo.container.ContainerException: Failed to redeploy [/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/deploy-staging/webapp/target/webapp.war]
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.redeploy(AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.java:176)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.deploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:81)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$DeployCallable.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:167)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$DeployCallable.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:136)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1164)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1147)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.redeployFile(CargoContainerAdapter.java:133)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.PasswordProtectedAdapterCargo.redeployFile(PasswordProtectedAdapterCargo.java:95)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.DeployPublisher.perform(DeployPublisher.java:113)
    at jenkins.tasks.SimpleBuildStep.perform(SimpleBuildStep.java:123)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.perform(BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.java:80)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$3.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:45)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:803)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:752)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:177)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:697)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1932)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://localhost:9090/manager/text/list
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1896)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1498)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.invoke(TomcatManager.java:577)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.list(TomcatManager.java:882)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.getStatus(TomcatManager.java:895)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.redeploy(AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.java:161)
    ... 19 more
java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://localhost:9090/manager/text/list
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1896)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1498)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.invoke(TomcatManager.java:577)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.list(TomcatManager.java:882)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.getStatus(TomcatManager.java:895)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.redeploy(AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.java:161)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.deploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:81)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$DeployCallable.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:167)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$DeployCallable.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:136)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1164)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1147)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.redeployFile(CargoContainerAdapter.java:133)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.PasswordProtectedAdapterCargo.redeployFile(PasswordProtectedAdapterCargo.java:95)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.DeployPublisher.perform(DeployPublisher.java:113)
    at jenkins.tasks.SimpleBuildStep.perform(SimpleBuildStep.java:123)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.perform(BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.java:80)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$3.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:45)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:803)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:752)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:177)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:697)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1932)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
Build step 'Deploy war/ear to a container' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: `java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://localhost:9090/manager/text/list` means that you don't have Tomcat Manager running on `localhost:9090`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. My webapps directory was empty. So, I installed tomcat9-admin and reinstalled tomcat9 by using the command `sudo apt install tomcat9 tomcat9-admin`. Then I restarted the tomcat service using `sudo service tomcat9 restart`. Here are my logs in jenkins:

```
Started by user Pritish
Running as SYSTEM
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/deploy-staging
Copied 1 artifact from "package" build number 5
[DeployPublisher][INFO] Attempting to deploy 1 war file(s)
[DeployPublisher][INFO] Deploying /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/deploy-staging/webapp/target/webapp.war to container Tomcat 9.x Remote with context null
  [/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/deploy-staging/webapp/target/webapp.war] is not deployed. Doing a fresh deployment.
  Deploying [/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/deploy-staging/webapp/target/webapp.war]
Finished: SUCCESS
```